# dojo wrapper or adapter classes

Tags: javascript, dojo, wrapper, adapter

I have recently started using dojo, I was wondering if there is anyway to implement a wrapper/adapter class. In pure javascript I would do the following

```
function Person(name){
    this.name=name;
}

function Employee(name,ID){
    this.Person=Person;
    this.Person(name);
    this.ID=ID;

    this.PromotedEmployee=PromotedEmployee;
}

function PromotedEmployee(employees){
    this.employees=employees;  //number of people working for him/her
}

var employee=new Employee("John Stamos",123);
employee.PromotedEmployee(10);   //promote to manage 10 people
```

How do I do this with dojo. Something as such does not work

```
dojo.declare("Person",null,{
    constructor: function(name){
        this.name=name;
    }
});

dojo.declare("PromotedEmployee",null,{
    constructor: function(employees){
        this.employees=employees;
    }
});

dojo.declare("Employee",[Person],{
    constructor: function(name,ID){
        this.ID=ID;
    },
    PromotedEmployee=PromotedEmployee;
});

var employee=new Employee("John Stamos",123);
employee.PromotedEmployee(10);   //promote to manage 10 people
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dojo.declare("PromotedEmployee",null,{
    employees: 0,
    constructor: function(){

    },
    promoteEmployees: function(employees){
         this.employees = employees;
    }
});
dojo.declare("Employee",[Person],{
    constructor: function(name,ID){
        this.ID=ID;
        this.promotedEmployee = new PromotedEmployee();
    }
});

var employee=new Employee("John Stamos",123);
employee.promotedEmployee.promoteEmployees(10);
```

//OR

```
dojo.declare("PromotedEmployee",null,{
        constructor: function(employees){
           this.employees = employees;
        }
    });
    dojo.declare("Employee",[Person],{
        constructor: function(name,ID,employees){
            this.ID=ID;
            this.promotedEmployee = new PromotedEmployee(employees);
        }
    });
     var employee=new Employee("John Stamos",123, 10);

//alert(employee.promotedEmployee.employees);
```

Comment: I thought about that approach, but I want an "is-a" not a "has-a" relationship.